# how to get index of text in a element HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code :

```
<button id="btn1"> Name of button <span> 1 </span> </button>
```

I want to replace the text of the button ("Name of button") to textbox element when clicking it

```
<button id="btn1"> <input type='text' value='Name of button'/> <span> 1 </span> </button>
```

So, I want to get index text of button to replace it.

Comment: `$('#btn1').html(function(ind, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.replace('Name of button', '<input type="text" value="Name of button"/>');
});`

Comment: An input tag inside a button tag would be useless, as in you wouldn't be able to enter text into the input without additional JavaScript to disable the default behavior of the button. Plus, input tags aren't allowed inside button tags by the HTML standards. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it does not meet HTML standards the below does work in Google Chrome

```js
$('#btn1').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).find("input").length == 0) {
    var span = $(this).find("span").detach();
    var buttonText = $(this).text();
    $(this).empty().append("<input type='text' value='" + buttonText + "'/>");
    $(this).append(span);
    $(this).find("input").focus();
  }
});

$('#btn1').on("blur", "input", function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="editable">Name of button<span> 1 </span> 
</button>
```

I've also added a little extra to put the value from the text box back into the label of the button as it looks to me like that might be what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $("#btn1").contents()[0].textContent = $("#text").val();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s8hf91e7/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```js
document.querySelector('#btn1').innerHTML
  .replace('Name of button', '<input type="text" value="Name of button" />');
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Name of button <span> 1 </span> 
</button>
```

If the answer can't meet your need, comment and I'll update it.